# Custom property (Identity Data) in Revit model got translated wrong

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit, forge, autodesk-model-derivative

We are experiencing troubles when using the model derivative API to translate and extract properties from a Revit Model.

[image]
[image]

As the screenshot implies, we have a custom property under Identity Data. But after translation its under Mark (the property on top of it).
It's a model created in Revit 2018.

Is this a bug?

kind regards

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been logged as `RVTLMV-4` in our internal case system to our engineering team to allocate time to investigate what happened yesterday and they're working on it. We will get back to you A.S.A.P. once there is any update. Apologizing for any inconvenience had caused to you.

Comment: Is there any news around resolving the bug?

Comment: Unfortunately, no... Just hang on, let me check with them, will get back here A.S.A.P.

Comment: Hi, a fresh update for you. Our engineering team has confirmed that it's a problem here, and planned to fix it. There is a great possibility that the fix would be available soon, but I cannot guarantee until it's available in the final release.

Comment: @ThomasVanDriessche Please delete the old translation and submit a new job, I have confirmed that the fix of `RVTLMV-4` has been released now.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing this issue too - custom properties appear to be coming through with "Cost" as the PropertyName. The ModelDerivative translation process seems to be the source of the bug. Happens on Revit 2018 or Revit 2019 model.

Is there any chance this issue can be escalated?

Our (live) Forge application relies on custom properties being correctly named and this current API release has broken our application when new models are uploaded.

Image of [Model Derivative JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWqle.png)

Image of [Properties in Revit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3sDC.png)

Answer (score 0):

@Eason Kang: FYI
I met this issue too. However, this issue happened when the translated field was not in the top of the Properties list. When this field was in the top, translation succeeded.

Hope this could give more information to your team.

[I attached the image as below. First screenshot, it translated correctly. The 3 following screenshots, it translated wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GsV6.png)